# Tensorflow Training using input queue gets stuck

Tags: python, multithreading, queue, tensorflow

I am trying to build a NN training similar to the one in [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/how_tos/reading_data/index.html#creating-threads-to-prefetch-using-queuerunner-objects) tutorial.

My code looks as follows:

```
def train():
    init_op = tf.initialize_all_variables()
    sess = tf.Session()
    sess.run(init_op)

    coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
    threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(sess=sess, coord=coord)

    step = 0

    try:
        while not coord.should_stop():
            step += 1
            print 'Training step %i' % step
            training = train_op()
            sess.run(training)

    except tf.errors.OutOfRangeError:
        print 'Done training - epoch limit reached.'
    finally:
        coord.request_stop()

    coord.join(threads)
    sess.close()
```

with

```
MIN_NUM_EXAMPLES_IN_QUEUE = 10
NUM_PRODUCING_THREADS = 1
NUM_CONSUMING_THREADS = 1

def train_op():
    images, true_labels = inputs()
    predictions = NET(images)
    true_labels = tf.cast(true_labels, tf.float32)
    loss = tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(predictions, true_labels)
    return OPTIMIZER.minimize(loss)


def inputs():
    filenames = [os.path.join(FLAGS.train_dir, filename) 
        for filename in os.listdir(FLAGS.train_dir) 
        if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(FLAGS.train_dir, filename))]
    filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer(filenames,
        num_epochs=FLAGS.training_epochs, shuffle=True)

    example_list = [_read_and_preprocess_image(filename_queue) 
        for _ in xrange(NUM_CONSUMING_THREADS)]

    image_batch, label_batch = tf.train.shuffle_batch_join(
        example_list,
        batch_size=FLAGS.batch_size,
        capacity=MIN_NUM_EXAMPLES_IN_QUEUE + (NUM_CONSUMING_THREADS + 2) * FLAGS.batch_size,
        min_after_dequeue=MIN_NUM_EXAMPLES_IN_QUEUE)

    return image_batch, label_batch
```

The tutorial says

> These require that you call `tf.train.start_queue_runners` before running any training or inference steps, or it will hang forever.

. I am calling `tf.train.start_queue_runners`, but the execution of `train()` still gets stuck at the first occurrence of `sess.run(training)`.

Does someone have an idea what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are redefining your network every time you try to run the training loop.

Remember that TensorFlow defines an execution graph, and then executes it.  You want to call your train_op() outside of the run loop, and you need to define that graph BEFORE you call `initialize_all_variables` and `tf.train.start_queue_runners`